# NuGet package(s) that are missing in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting the following error while move the Xamarin Form project.

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this
>   computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more
>   information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The
>   missing file is
>   ....\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.0.6186\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\Xamarin.Forms.targets.

I can't find any solution to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be also a problem with leftover directives in .csproj when you upgraded Xamarin.Forms. So, check what XF version are you using and remove all the lines in *.csproj* where directives are referencing wrong version. They are usually located at the bottom of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The most common cause and resolution of this error message is documented in the following troubleshooting article:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/nuget-packages-missing/

Essentially, certain configurations of NuGet hard code the package imports into the .csproj file itself. The most frequent time I've seen this behavior is when a Xamarin.Forms app is created in Visual Studio and migrated over to Xamarin Studio; however it can happen in other cases.

The offending lines in the .csproj file look something like this:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Maps">
    <HintPath>..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.1.3.1.6296\lib\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Import Project="..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.1.3.1.6296\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10+Xamarin.iOS10\Xamarin.Forms.targets'))" />
```

Deleting these lines (or commenting them out) generally resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned issue was resolved by move the `package` folder to the root folder.

Is there any way to change the package folder path?